# Maze Game - Late 70's / Early 80's - Battleship-esk - What's it name?

Tags: identify-this-game, two-player

I am looking for the name of a Late 70's / early 80's board game.

The basic design was based on Battle Ship. Each of the two players had a clam shell case where they built their own maze at the bottom and tracked their opponent at the top. Read and green cases, with blue green chips used to build the mazes.

The goal was to follow your opponent's maze by blindly bumping into corners, trying to figure out the path to the goal, which was capturing the other guys pawn before he got to yours.

It was a great strategy game and I would love to dig up, or recreate a copy to play with my kids.

Any hints at the name of this game? And who the manufacturer was?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds to me like Pathfinder which was a game of my childhood.

BGG link - https://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/2884/pathfinder

Comment: Wow. That is it. It is amazing how easy it is to find something on line if you have the name, and how impossible it is if you don't. thank you.  :-)

Answer (score 4):

The game [reviewed here on Board Game Geek](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1140096/vintage-maze-game-delivers-exactly-what-was-promis) seems to fit the description quite well

Could this be it?

This is Pathfinder published by MB.

[image: Pathfinder by MB]

Comment: Ninja-ed... Looks like I should have refresh the page before submitting my answer ;-)

Comment: beewee - thanks for taking the extra time to include an image